# Unable to set BackgroundColor with MvxBind

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to change the RecyclerView's item color.  The code below only shows the RelativeLayout which is the root layout of the item layout.

I have the following code:

(Item) Layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_listitem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_left_shoppinglistitems"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
    local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor NativeColor(Background)">

  ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public class ListItem : TableData, IListItem
{
    ...            
    public MvxColor Background { get { return new MvxColor(255,189,69,128); } }
    ...
}
```

I have added MvvmCross.Plugin.Color to both Droid and Core project. I have no idea why this is not working?  I can see Background property being accessed but the color is not being set to the set test value (in the future I want the color to be based on another boolean property). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Checks that you have the plugin color installed and it´s initialized. I use binding in this way: 
local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor Background, Converter=NativeColor"

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your code and it seems to work fine. The color declaration is correct, and the binding also. I highly doubt the problem you have is in the code you are showing. Make sure you use the latest color package ( 5.5.0.0 ). I supose your list is showing in the app? Maybe post the full xaml layout of your cells.

[image]